# Getting partial api data from firebase functions- actions-on-google

Tags: actions-on-google

When I try to access external API's for my google action from my webhook which is hosted on firebase functions, I am getting back only partial content. It stops getting the whole data provided by the api.
For example I tried getting data from wikipedia api using this code

```
var request = require('request');//required module
//inside the function
request({ method: 'GET',url:'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts&format=json&explaintext=&exsectionformat=plain&redirects=&titles=11_September'},function (error, response, body)
        {
            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) 
            {
                console.log(body);  
            }

        });
app.ask('data obtained');
```

Can anyone please help me out with this.
I am having a pay as you go firebase account that allows egress of data.

Answer (score 1):

From just the code fragment, the problem is that you're replying to the user outside the callback from `request()`. This means that it is handled immediately and the function may end before the entire body has been received. Try something like this (I've also changed `ask()` to `tell()` since you're not prompting for another response here, and you shouldn't leave the microphone open.)

```
var request = require('request');//required module
//inside the function
request({ method: 'GET',url:'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts&format=json&explaintext=&exsectionformat=plain&redirects=&titles=11_September'},function (error, response, body)
        {
            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) 
            {
                console.log(body);  
                app.tell('data obtained');
            }

        });
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Allen. But I have tried both. As Node is asynchronous the results were the same.

Comment: You may wish to include more of the code in the question, then.

Comment: Strange... I'm using the 'same' code more or less with my 'Wikipedia friend' action. You can see the code at: https://wikipedia-friend.glitch.me/ 
If you want to double check that it's not firebase - try your code from another NodeJS server.

Comment: I will sure try that and will get back